# Can not use different namespaces for different build flavors in Android library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I tried to use different package name `namespace` for different product flavors in my Android library project. With the followed configuration

```
    productFlavors {
        foo {
            namespace 'com.example.foo'
            manifestPlaceholders = [pkgName:"com.example.foo"]
        }
        // the later one always win
        bar {
            namespace 'com.example.bar'
            manifestPlaceholders = [pkgName:"com.example.bar"]
        }
    }
```

it looks like `namespace` not worked in different product flavor. it always use the latter namespace even I switch to a different product flavor.

I tried use `manifestPlaceholders` with `package` attribute from `AndroidManfiest.xml` in vain with the followed warning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="${pkgName}">

</manifest>
```

> Cannot use placeholder for the package in the manifest; set applicationId in build.gradle instead

How can I use different namespaces for different build flavors in Android library?

Comment: Did you try using `applicationId` instead of `manifestPlaceholders`?

Comment: @Stephan `> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Library projects cannot set applicationId.` see the [note](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish-library/prep-lib-release#choose-namespace) in documentation

Comment: I see, but does it need a package in the manifest? Here (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) it says: "You can omit the package name if the resource is provided by your app (including if it is provided by a library dependency, because library resources are merged into yours)"

Comment: Apparently it needs to match "package name", not appId, so it is same for all product flavors. But it needs to be declared in each module separately, because each module will have different package name